# An unexpected variable reference changing during Julia Zygote gradient pullback

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I'm using Julia Flux.jl to train models. But when I customize my model, there is an issue the variable reference in gradient pullback function doesn't behave as expected. For simplicity, the issue code is simplified and shown as following

```
let
    x=rand(Float32, (10,1))
    
    v_layer=[
        Dense(10, 11),
        Dense(10, 12),
    ]
    
    ps=Flux.Params([
                vcat((collect.(params.(v_layer)))...)...,
                ])
    
    function model(x)
        out=x
        for (layer_idx, layer)=enumerate(v_layer)
            @show layer_idx, size(x)
            out=layer(x)
        end
        return out
    end
    gs=gradient(ps) do
        sum(model(x))
    end
end
```

If we run the code, the size of `x` in for loop will change according to the `@show` macro output as following

```
(layer_idx, size(x)) = (1, (10, 1))
(layer_idx, size(x)) = (2, (11, 1))
```

And we will get the following error message

```
DimensionMismatch("A has dimensions (12,10) but B has dimensions (11,1)")
```

I think the reference change of `out` in for loop should not change the reference of `x`, but that happened. Besides if we put the `function model` whole body inside `gradient do` as following

```
gs=gradient(ps) do
    out=x
    for (layer_idx, layer)=enumerate(v_layer)
        @show layer_idx, size(x)
        out=layer(x)
    end
    sum(out)
end
```

worked just fine. Why is this?

**PS.** A slightly more complex but more practical version code is as follows and has the same error.

```
let
    v_layer_A=[
        Dense(10, 11),
        Dense(11, 12),
    ]
    v_layer_B=[
        Dense(10, 11),
        Dense(10, 12),
    ]
    
    x=rand(Float32, (10,1))
    
    ps=Flux.Params([
                vcat((collect.(params.(v_layer_A)))...)...,
                vcat((collect.(params.(v_layer_B)))...)...,
                ])
    
    function model(x)
        out=x
        for (idx, (layer_A, layer_B))=enumerate(zip(v_layer_A, v_layer_B))
            @show idx, size(x)
            out_A=layer_A(out)
            out_B=layer_B(x)
            out=out_A.*out_B
        end
        return out
    end
    
    gs=gradient(ps) do
        sum(model(x))
    end
end
```

Comment: The weird thing to me is how x could possibly change. It's never reassigned, and even if some method mutated x, it couldn't turn it from a (10,1) Matrix to a (11,1) Matrix. The only (11,1) Matrix that shows up is v_layer[1](x), which is assigned to out in the 1st iteration. Is it possible that in the original unsimplified code with the error, the line was more akin to `x = layer(x)`, even indirectly via `out = layer(x)` then `x = out`?

Comment: Zygote has weird bugs! It re-writes the code, and gets it wrong here? I think I've seen this bug but can't find the issue. Sometimes even`out = identity(x)` will convince it that these are distinct objects with the same value, although here it seems to give slightly different bugs. 
 
The code is weird though, as it discards the result of `v_layer[1](x)` completely, so that layer need not exist.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Is there a macro not written here? Because that's the only way I can think of rewriting code.

Comment: There are no additional macros or other high-level code, just run the above code at the top level to reproduce the error.

Comment: Zygote has its fingers pretty deep in the machinery, it acts on some intermediate representation half way through the compilation process, differentiates that, and feeds it back to Julia. Anything within the `gradient` call is traced and re-written this way.

Comment: The "ps. more complicated" example seems to be fixed by `out=identity(x)`. Or at least it runs and produces nonzero gradients. BTW you can write `ps = Flux.params(v_layer_A, v_layer_B)` instead of unpacking by hand, it should recurse into things.